# Get the column name that match string comparison on multiple column-string comparison

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp

Im building a simple search system, I have a simple form and I'm doing a query like this:

```
Select * from table where column_a like'%term%' or columnn_b like '%term%' or column_c like'%term%';
```

It is possible to determine which column was that the string %term% match (without using a bunch of if statements)?, actually I'm using CakePHP, but at this point I will not care if I need to build the query manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the identity of the matched column is lost in the evaluation of your `or` clauses.  You'll need to do some post-processing (i.e., the "bunch of if statements" you were trying to avoid) to identify exactly which column in your result set matched.

Comment: sad, I was reading about this and as you say the pointer of the column that match is lose during the process :(